# Make a for loop to show data object from API in render using Charts Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, charts

I need to show some data from API in the Chart Reacts (https://canvasjs.com/react-charts/chart-index-data-label/)

This is my API in front:

```
 //API Gains stats
           fetch(`${API}/api/gains/getstatgains` 
        ,{
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'authorization': `Bearer ${tok}`
            }
        })
        .then(results => {
            return results.json();
        })
        .then(res => {
            var statsgains = res.result;
              if(res.success === true){
                // console.log("chart ", res);
                for (var i = 0; i< statsgains.length; i++){
                    this.setState({ gains_label: statsgains[i]._id });
                    this.setState({ gains_used: statsgains[i].total });
                    // console.log("gains utilisés : ", statsgains[i].total);
                    // console.log("gains utilisés : ", statsgains[i]._id);
                }
              }
        })
```

And this is the Chart code in `render()`:

```
var { gains_used, gains_label } = this.state;

 //Gains stats
         const options_gains = {
            animationEnabled: true,
            exportEnabled: true,
            theme: "light2", //"light1", "dark1", "dark2"
            title:{
                text: "Simple Column Chart with Index Labels"
            },
            data: [{
                type: "column", //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc
                //indexLabel: "{y}", //Shows y value on all Data Points
                indexLabelFontColor: "#5A5757",
                indexLabelPlacement: "outside",
                dataPoints: [
                    { x: 20, y: gains_used, indexLabel: gains_label }
                ]
            }]
         }
```

In Postman I have this result (http://localhost:3001/api/gains/getstatgains):

```
"success": true,
"message": "SUCCESS",
"result": [
    {
        "_id": "BBBBBBBBB",
        "total": 2
    },
    {
        "_id": "cccccccccc",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": "AAAAAAAA",
        "total": 3
    }
]
}
```

I think I need to make a for loop in data to shows all the result, but in my browser the chart shows only "AAAAAAAA".

Comment: What shape does the data need to be in before sending it to the charts lib?

Comment: its in the line :   { x: 20, y: gains_used, indexLabel: gains_label }

Comment: I see, so you're just looping through the results and setting the state on last result, so just the last item is your result. Why not swap out the for loop for `.map()` which returns an array of transformed results?

Comment: can you give me please an example according to my post ? .map() not workin if i use ir before the return()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added this to explain comment. This would replace your last `.then()`, the one with the loop.

```
.then(({ result, success }) => success
    ? result.map(({ _id, total }) => ({ gains_label: _id, gains_used: total }))
    : []
).then(dataPoints => this.setState({ dataPoints }))
```

Now in render, you can just replace

```
var { gains_used, gains_label } = this.state;
```

with:

```
const { dataPoints } = this.state;
```

And instead of hard-coding like this:

```
            data: [{
                type: "column", //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc
                //indexLabel: "{y}", //Shows y value on all Data Points
                indexLabelFontColor: "#5A5757",
                indexLabelPlacement: "outside",
                dataPoints: [
                    { x: 20, y: gains_used, indexLabel: gains_label }
                ]
            }]
```

Just do:

```
            data: [{
                type: "column", //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc
                //indexLabel: "{y}", //Shows y value on all Data Points
                indexLabelFontColor: "#5A5757",
                indexLabelPlacement: "outside",
                dataPoints
            }]
```

Edit: to increment x by 10, try:

```
.then(({ result, success }) => success 
  ? result.map(({ _id, total }) => ({ x: 20, y: total, indexLabel: _id, }))
          .map((obj, i) => ({ ...obj, x: obj.x + (i * 10) }))
  : [] 
).then(dataPoints => this.setState({ dataPoints }))
```

Or with reduce:

```
  .then(({ result, success }) => success
    ? result.reduce((arr, { _id, total }) => ([
      ...arr, {
        x: arr.length ? arr[arr.length - 1].x + 10 : 20,
        y: total, indexLabel: _id } ]), [])
    : [])
  .then(dataPoints => this.setState({ dataPoints }))
```

Comment: Replace last `.then()` in your example with it

Comment: What is the output of it now, an array of objects? did you see my edit at the bottom?

Comment: i made a console.log like this :   .then(({ result, success }) => success
    ? console.log(result.map(({ _id, total }) => ({ gains_label: _id, gains_used: total, x: 20 })) )
    : []   and it shows my data, but the chart is empty !

Comment: That makes sense bc your lib expects x, y & indexLabel, but I originally gave gains_label etc. as the final result. Try the updated version

Comment: i tried it, no result .. it's result.map(.. not results.map(.. ) no ? because the line : .then(({ result, success }) => success is grey, and why res.success ? thanks

Comment: Yeah should be result.map not results and success instead of res.success

Comment: this show the chart : 
        .then(({ result, success }) => success
        ? result.map(({ _id, total }) => ({ x: 20, y: total, indexLabel: _id, }))
        : []
    ).then(dataPoints => this.setState({ dataPoints }))

BUT, i want that 'x' to be incrementd +10 with each data

because x is hardcoding here :/

Comment: how can i make a for loop in the .map to increment x please ?

Comment: This should work .then(({ result, success }) => success 
  ? result.reduce(arr, ({ _id, total }) => ([
    ...arr,
    {
      x: arr.length ? arr[arr.length - 1].x + 10 : 20,
      y: total,
      indexLabel: _id
    }
  ]), []) 
  : [] 
).then(dataPoints => this.setState({ dataPoints }))

Comment: the chart is empty again xD
i have this in browser console : Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: arr is not defined

Comment: You can put parentheses around `reduce((arr` and `total }))` or look at my other edit which uses a second map.

Comment: what means :  ...obj OR ...arr, please ?

Comment: it's spread operator, to refer to all elements of a collection without the collection itself. so if `a = [1, 2, 3]` and `b = [...a]`, then b is `[1, 2, 3]` not `[[1, 2, 3]]`